# Programming languages supported by meego

Tags: c++, meego

What are the programming languages supported by Meego ? Where Can I get any sample library built in meego for some  basic analysis in ubuntu environment...

I am going to test libraries built in meego...I am trying to analyse the type of libraries I may be getting..

Answer (score 2):

The preferred library for Meego will be Qt. Qt applications can be written in many languages, but the preferred language is C++. Python bindings will probably be available.

Security Tools

Answer (score 1):

C++ - see http://qt.nokia.com/products/platform/meego/